# Need Help Finding a Replacement for sys.sysprocesses

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-2016, upgrade

The SQL 2016 Data Migration Assistant (Upgrade Advisor) is saying that I need to stop using old system table references.  Namely, it wants me to stop using sysdatabases and sysprocesses.

I have some code that's logging session information based on data from sysprocesses.  Included in that log is the database ID of the spid (session_id).

I have been searching online and have found only two possible replacements, neither of which work fully due to reasons explained below.

Option 1 (sys.dm_tran_locks) - This option seems to work rather reliably if I link back to sys.dm_exec_sessions but I noticed that it will never return a result if the session_id's database context is master or tempdb.  That means I will not be able to reliably fetch the resource_database_id for any session_id that is using master or tempdb.  I also cannot just assume it since there are at least two possible contexts to choose from.

Option 2 (sys.dm_exec_requests) - This option only works on session_id's that are actively running.  Idle/suspended session_id's do not appear in the list.

If I cannot get the dbid for session_id's that are suspended and/or are using the master database context then I will have a gap in my logs.

Is there any other way to reliably fetch this information without the use of sys.sysprocesses?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve .e.g. find blocking or locks ? There can be a way to achieve if you let us know  what you mean by ` have some code that's logging session information based on data from sysprocesses.` ? e,g. using `sys.dm_tran_locks` etc

Comment: How reliable / meaningful is the database_id anyway? If someone is in master and querying a join between two databases or a union across all databases... what difference does it make? Why is this information necessary for sessions that are idle at query time? Their last query may have been against database 1 but their next query might be against database 12.

Comment: @Kin I have one procedure that is logging blocking and another that is logging some audit information about currently logged on sessions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand but why wouldn't I be able to obtain the current session's database context?   I was able to do it in the past and I can still get it from sysprocesses?  Whether they 3 part reference another database and/or plan to query another database in their next batch I should be able to obtain the current session's context using the DMVs reliably.

Comment: My point is I don't know how reliable or useful the info you're getting from sysprocesses is ... okay, database_id has a value, but is it the *right* value? Are you actually using that value for anything (other than not violating a NOT NULL constraint in your logging table)? The blocking information you're logging, for example, has the information about database / schema / object already. Why do you care what's in the database_id column? If a lock in database 1 is blocking a query running in database 2 joining tables in databases 3 and 4, what 1 value of database_id do you want?

Comment: @AaronBertrand One of the queries using this information is a blocking log.  It keeps track of blocking occurrences in the server and logs the information to a table (spid, query, statement text, duration, etc... so database is important).  This query polls.  So though it is not fool-proof because you could have gaps depending on your poll interval, having the database is helpful.  The other query using this is a login audit.  Again, it's polling because we don't want to add strain to the server, though I think this may be able to be re-written using events.

Comment: My point about capturing blocking queries and having that info already: If you capture the plan for the blocks instead of just the query text, you can pull *all* of the databases involved from the XML, instead of relying on the single, arbitrary choice available to you in sys.sysprocesses. (Also, a login audit will often just tell you the login's default database, and not provide any information about what database context they switched to once they connected.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I see.  Sounds like I need to re-write these queries entirely.  Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Or just get a monitoring tool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft is aware of the lack of replacements. You can upvote & watch these Connect items for more details:

[Deprecation of sysprocesses - DMV's doesn't fully replace all columns - by Tony Rogerson SQL](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891986-deprecation-of-sysprocesses-dmv-s-doesn-t-fully)

[There is no real alternative to master.dbo.sysprocesses - by GV1973](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/726164/there-is-no-real-alternative-to-master-dbo-sysprocesses)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is all I was able to find.  I was hoping there was more information that i was missing.  Thank you for confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping System Tables to System Views:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx

A combination of sys.dm_exec_sessions & sys.dm_exec_requests is likely to contain most of what you need.

If you post your query we should be able help you to write a SQL2016-compliant version.