# Is it normal to constantly have 30+ connections to ‘master’ database in MS SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, connections, max-connections, master-system-database

In troubleshooting why I was seeing so many connections to one of our internally used databases in SQL Server 2012.

A query I found online that had been helpful to me was this:

```
 SELECT DB_NAME(sP.dbid) AS the_database
         , COUNT(sP.spid) AS total_database_connections
 FROM sys.sysprocesses sP
 GROUP BY DB_NAME(sP.dbid)
 ORDER BY 1;
```

However, although after fixing an issue, I've seen connections to our own custom database go back to normal levels, I'm always seeing the number of connections to the `master` database always at over 30 connections.

Is this normal for SQL Server 2012?  Anyone else getting 30 or more connections to `master` when running this query?

Comment: Are the spids less than 50? If so, these are system processes and can be ignored. If they are over 50, then show us more info for those rows.

Comment: Hi Tara, how can I find out what the spids of those connections are?  Is there a query you can point me to?

Comment: `spid` in `sysprocesses` = `session_id` in modern views.

Answer (score 5):

30 system processes is absolutely not unheard of, and actually sounds better than normal.

However, you should not be using `sysprocesses`, which is deprecated and only exists for backward compatibility reasons - see the important note [right at the top of the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx). (If you're using it solely for the database column, see [this recent question, and the comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/163625/1186).)

You should be looking at [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) - this view has a column called `is_user_process` that allows you to identify your processes and distinguish them from system processes (the old < 50 trick is no longer reliable on modern versions of SQL Server).

Just as an example, on my local dev machine - where I can assure you nothing is going on - I have the following rows:

```
sys.sysprocesses                                    62
sys.dm_exec_sessions                                68
sys.dm_exec_sessions where is_user_process = 1      26
```

The majority of those 26 user processes are just connections to the instance (which is on a VM guest) held open by Visual Studio Code on the host.

The other 42 are normal, sleeping, background system processes like `LOG WRITER`, `LOCK MONITOR`, `XE DISPATCHER`, 'CHECKPOINT', etc. It's not like you can get rid of these.

You could also compare the output of the undocumented `sys.sp_who2`:

```
EXEC sys.sp_who2;                       -- 64 rows in my case
EXEC sys.sp_who2 @loginame = N'active'; -- 40 rows in my case
```

Or limiting to actual running processes in [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx).

But for deeper insight into what processes are doing on your system, you're better off using something like Adam Machanic's [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) or a proper monitoring tool (disclaimer: [I work for one of those](https://sentryone.com/)).